# Content Organizer Permissions

Tags: content-organizer

When using the content organizer in SharePoint 2010, do users need to have contributor permissions in the destination document library, or just to the Drop Off Library?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently I just needed to go one more page on the Bing search results :)

The answer is here: http://www.scottjamison.com/blog/2010/11/the-sharepoint-2010-content-organizer/

> Two of the questions I get regularly
>   on the content organizer:
>
> 1. Does a user need write permissions on the destination location? 
>      Answer: Actually, no! The content
>      organizer will move the content to
>      the new location whether or not the
>      contributing user has access to the
>      destination location.
> 2. What account is used for the “Modified By” property on the
>      destination document? Answer: The
>      system will retain the original
>      contributor. (The system does not
>      mark the document as updated by
>      ‘system’ or ‘admin’ or anything like
>      that.)
>
>    This is an interesting situation —
>      it means that users can effectively
>      add content into a place where they
>      technically don’t have permissions.
>      Not directly, mind you. But in effect.